# Question about how to couple round servo shaft to flat shaft

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design

I'm looking to control a commercial deadbolt using a small servo, motor, or gear motor. The deadbolt has a common Schlage cylinder such as [this one](https://images.homedepot-static.com/productImages/39eda453-f5f0-4c06-bf4c-d32bc4a8c01f/svn/prime-line-door-kits-locks-trims-e-2103-c3_1000.jpg) that has a flat shaft that runs through a slotted hole in the deadbolt. In [this diagram](http://www.mrlock.com/image/catalog/mfg/ilc/lori_deadbolt/4500-parts-breakdown.jpg) the shaft is labeled 'tailpiece' and is connected to the thumb-turn on the inside of the door.

Most servos and electric motors come with short, round shafts on the end of them. Presumably in common usage a gear or cam is mounted to that shaft with a screw. For this situation, it would be convenient to couple the two shafts directly together inline, such that the motor would replace the thumb-turn.

I'm not in any way a mechanical engineer, so I'm really grasping at straws but I think what I need is a [shaft adapter/coupling](https://www.mcmaster.com/shaft-couplings)? Something that would encase the round shaft of the servo on one side and the flat shaft of the lock cylinder on the other and clamp down on both.

Alternatively the server / motor could be mounted perpendicular to the flat shaft and two gears could mesh to make a 90 degree angle. I don't have anything to measure torque properly, but I know the thumb-turn is not quite an inch in radius and it takes more force to turn it then it takes to pull a stiff trigger, so probably 5-10 lb inches? I feel like the gear-based option might not stand up to that. Then again, the whole lock set could do with some grease. It's an old house.

---

Another thought I just had was a through-hole motor. Or servo. Do they make through-hole servos?

---

This is a one-off solution for home application, but I'll document it and share that documentation so it'd be nice if the solution was broadly applicable to common lockset configurations. I'm leaving the standard keyway on the outside of the door for power outages. It may be hard to turn due to the servo on the other end, but it would be infrequently used.

Now that I've disassembled it and refreshed my memory of what it looks like on the inside, I realize there's a second option. The thumb-turn engages the lock cylinder via a component that I don't know the name for. On the thumb-turn side it's a washer with an oblong inner diameter. On the door side it's a collar with a matching outer diameter.

Here's some photos of the actual parts: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Io0Tz.jpg

I could potentially make a wood part that fits over the door-side collar and could screw into the arms of a servo motor. Might be easier than a shaft-coupler.

Comment: Many places sell shaft adaptors - trick is finding who sells the one you want...

Comment: I'm not too familiar with where to look. Only names I know are McMaster-Carr and Grainger. Everything they have is $40+ and way sturdier than what I'd need. Also there are lots of couplers for similarly sized/shaped shafts. I didn't see adapters for flat shafts. I guess I could put something in there to make the flat shaft rounder.

Comment: ^this. A half-round that goes behind the flat, allowing the set screw to engage the flat without deflecting it is not uncommon practice.

Comment: Can you give more context? How failsafe does this need to be? Are you making thousands of these, or would a hand-fettled widget be OK?

Comment: @SolarMike  Added details and photographs. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: @JonathanRSwift Added details and photographs. Thanks for the assistance